# Bootstrap class to adjust the width of a panel

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap panel for my dashboard so for that I have to place 5 bootstrap panel inline so for that I tried `class="col-lg-2 col-md-3"` or `class="col-lg-3 col-md-3"` these  two classes but these two classes are only possible for even nos like 4 or 6 but its not applying for odd nos like 5 and 7 So I tried inline css like `style="width: 200px"` but its not working in all browsers so what should I do now.

I am attaching a snap for this please take a look into this.
[**snap Img**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Of8wZ.png)

so far what I tried

```
<section class="content">
<!-- Small boxes (Stat box) -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3" style="width: 220px">
            <!-- small box -->
            <div class="small-box bg-primary">
                <div class="inner">
                    <h3>
                        <span id=claimedAmount></span>
                    </h3>
                    <p>Total Claimed</p>
                </div>
                <div class="icon">
                    <i class="fa fa-inr bg-icon"></i>
                </div>
                <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/localConveyance/list" class="small-box-footer">More info 
                <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3" style="width: 220px">
            <!-- small box -->
            <div class="small-box bg-yellow">
                <div class="inner">
                    <h3>
                        <span id=pendingAmount></span>
                    </h3>

                    <p>Pending Approval</p>
                </div>
                <div class="icon">
                    <i class="fa fa-inr bg-icon"></i>
                </div>
                <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/localConveyance/list" class="small-box-footer">More info 
                <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3" style="width: 220px">
            <!-- small box -->
            <div class="small-box bg-green">
                <div class="inner">
                    <h3>
                        <span id=settledAmount></span>
                    </h3>
                    <p>Settled</p>
                </div>
                <div class="icon">
                    <i class="fa fa-inr bg-icon"></i>
                </div>
                <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/localConveyance/list" class="small-box-footer">More info 
                <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- ./col -->
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3" style="width: 218px">
            <!-- small box -->
            <div class="small-box bg-navy">
                <div class="inner">
                    <h3>
                        <span id=pendingSettledAmount></span>
                    </h3>

                    <p>Pending Settlement</p>
                </div>
                <div class="icon">
                    <i class="fa fa-inr bg-icon"></i>
                </div>
                <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/localConveyance/list" class="small-box-footer">More info 
                <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- ./col -->
        <!-- ./col -->    
        <!-- ./col -->
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3" style="width: 218px">
            <!-- small box -->
            <div class="small-box bg-red">
                <div class="inner">
                    <h3>
                        <span id=rejectedAmount></span>
                    </h3>

                    <p>Rejected</p>
                </div>
                <div class="icon">
                    <i class="fa fa-inr bg-icon"></i>
                </div>
                <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/localConveyance/list" class="small-box-footer">More info
                <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.row -->
    <!-- Main row -->
</section>
```

Comment: you can post your code or fiddle link??

Comment: never included code as snaps sorry but this violates SO Rules yes you posted code after but should have removed the image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Below code and remove inline css, and see [Updeted Bootply Demo](http://www.bootply.com/szMkz9gmwF)

HTML:

```
<section class="content">
    <!-- Small boxes (Stat box) -->
                <div class="row"> 
                    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3">
                        <!-- small box -->
                        <div class="small-box bg-primary">
                            <div class="inner">
                                <h3>
                                    <span id=claimedAmount></span>
                                </h3>

                                <p>Total Claimed</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="icon">
                                <i class="fa fa-inr bg-icon"></i>
                            </div>
                            <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/localConveyance/list" class="small-box-footer">More info <i
                                class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3">
                        <!-- small box -->
                        <div class="small-box bg-yellow">
                            <div class="inner">
                                <h3>
                                    <span id=pendingAmount></span>
                                </h3>

                                <p>Pending Approval</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="icon">
                                <i class="fa fa-inr bg-icon"></i>
                            </div>
                            <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/localConveyance/list" class="small-box-footer">More info <i
                                class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3">
                        <!-- small box -->
                        <div class="small-box bg-green">
                            <div class="inner">
                                <h3>
                                    <span id=settledAmount></span>
                                </h3>

                                <p>Settled</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="icon">
                                <i class="fa fa-inr bg-icon"></i>
                            </div>
                            <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/localConveyance/list" class="small-box-footer">More info <i
                                class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <!-- ./col -->
                    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3">
                        <!-- small box -->
                        <div class="small-box bg-navy">
                            <div class="inner">
                                <h3>
                                    <span id=pendingSettledAmount></span>
                                </h3>

                                <p>Pending Settlement</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="icon">
                                <i class="fa fa-inr bg-icon"></i>
                            </div>
                            <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/localConveyance/list" class="small-box-footer">More info <i
                                class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- ./col -->

                    <!-- ./col -->


                    <!-- ./col -->
                    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3">
                        <!-- small box -->
                        <div class="small-box bg-red">
                            <div class="inner">
                                <h3>
                                    <span id=rejectedAmount></span>
                                </h3>

                                <p>Rejected</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="icon">
                                <i class="fa fa-inr bg-icon"></i>
                            </div>
                            <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/localConveyance/list" class="small-box-footer">More info <i
                                class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.row -->
                <!-- Main row -->

            </section>
```

Comment: Okay but the same problem  actually its not fit to the browser there is a gap in both side.

Comment: if you don't have any space so you can give width:20% in col-lg-2 class.

Comment: And see my updeted demo

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-1">1</div>
    <div class="col-md-2">2</div>
    <div class="col-md-2">3</div>
    <div class="col-md-2">4</div>
    <div class="col-md-2">5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: its okay but its not fit to the screen in both side some gaps are there

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using bootstrap you can use the css flex property to align all the colums correctly like this:

```
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item">flex item 1</div>
  <div class="flex-item">flex item 2</div>
  <div class="flex-item">flex item 3</div>
  <div class="flex-item">flex item 2</div>
  <div class="flex-item">flex item 3</div>
</div>




 <style>
    .flex-container {
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: flex;
        -webkit-justify-content: flex-end;
        justify-content: flex-end;
        width: 400px;
        height: 250px;
        background-color: lightgrey;
    }

    .flex-item {
        background-color: cornflowerblue;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        margin: 10px;
    }
 </style>
```

try this,i hope it will help you.